# Angular Material 11.0.3 + Tailwind CSS not working

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-material, tailwind-css

I'm using Angular CLI 11.0.6 on NodeJS 14.15.4 to make a web application for learning Angular(11.0.7) along with TailwindCSS 2.0.2. I followed this tutorial to install Tailwind but prior to that I added Angular Material. But after adding Material, I can't seem to run the code. Trying to execute `ng s`   gives error

`Your project is not using the default builders for "build". The Angular Material schematics cannot add a theme to the workspace configuration if the builder has been changed.`

I believe this is due to the fact that the tutorial made me change the *angular.json* file

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
-   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
+   "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",                   
    "options": {
+     "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
      ...
    }
    ...
  },
  "serve": {
-   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
+   "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
    "options": {
+     "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
      ...
    }
    ...
  },
  "test": {
-   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
+   "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
    "options": {
+     "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
      ...
    }
    ...
  },
```

So the lines starting with **+** was added and **-** was removed. Please help me out if you can as I'm learning Angular to get into a job in these troubled times. Thanks a lot for helping or reading this.

Comment: I assume you are trying to add Angular Material using the Schematics `ng add ..`, try to install it manually : https://github.com/angular/components/commit/ca7fff51603602abe682c510b1f67c17f475044e?short_path=27d0824

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6701831/linh Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Used `ng add` to add Angular Material, now everything works. Thanks Linh for that.